# Which Italian provinces get ceded to the Pope on creation of HRE?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm trying to create HRE and the Pope is asking for several provinces to be ceded in exchange. How is it determined which counties must be handed over? In my case he wants Ferrara, Ravenna, Spoleto and Urbino. Ferrara and Ravenna are both a part of my demesne and as a result I'm reluctant to hand them over.

Comment: Are you asking for what happened in real history, or a strategic hint, or something else?

Comment: This is about a video game, don't mind if it's a little bit different from history. I want to know how the game computes the provinces to hand over so that I can keep my demesne at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pope always asks for Rome, Ravenna, Ferrara, Urbino, and Spoleto, but only if the current holder has other titles owned.

See `form_the_hre_early` in `realm_decisions.txt`